# Why showing incorrect even sum in c++?

Tags: c++

when I was trying to calculate the sum of even numbers the result isn't correct if the starting number is negative?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    signed int startingNumber, upperLimit;
    signed int result = 0;
    cout << "please enter the starting number: "; cin >> startingNumber;
    cout << "please enter the upper limit: "; cin >> upperLimit;

    while (true) {
        if (startingNumber % 2 != 0) result += startingNumber;
            if (upperLimit == startingNumber) break;
            startingNumber++;
         }
    cout << "The result is: " << result << endl;
}
```

But when I run the script the following is the result:

```
please enter the starting number: -2
please enter the upper limit: 4
The result is: 3
```

I think the result should be 4 not 3, as the calculation is -2 +0 + 2 + 4 = 4.

Regards,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `(startingNumber % 2 != 0)` with this:

```
(startingNumber % 2 == 0)
```

Because what you want is to sum the **even** numbers and not **odd** numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `if (startingNumber % 2 != 0)` which means it will only add up numbers which are **not** divisible by two, resulting in -1 + 1 + 3 = 3. The condition in the if statement is only true if the remainder of dividing `startingNumber` by two is non-zero, which will be the case for odd numbers.

Use `if (startingNumber % 2 == 0) result += startingNumber;` instead and you should get the right sum.